# rethinkdb index-rebuild: Connection refused

Tags: rethinkdb

I recently decided to finally upgrade from v1.15 to v2.2.1, created a clone of the server, and intuitively upgraded rethink using apt.

But now something strange happens: rethinkdb service won't start because of old indexes, and index-rebuild screams it can't connect.

What am I missing?

```
$rethinkdb --version
rethinkdb 2.2.1~0precise (GCC 4.6.3)

$ service rethinkdb start
rethinkdb: default: Starting instance. (logging to `/var/lib/rethinkdb/default/data/log_file')

$ cat /var/lib/rethinkdb/default/data/log_file | tail -1
2015-12-09T14:16:47.011883463 0.051804s error: Encountered an index from before RethinkDB 1.16, which is no longer supported.  You can use RethinkDB 2.1 to update your secondary index.

$ rethinkdb index-rebuild
Error when connecting: Could not connect to localhost:28015. Error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Are you certain that your RethinkDB instance is using the default ports? You want to add those specific ports to this command if so => https://rethinkdb.com/docs/troubleshooting/#my-secondary-index-is-outdated

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade from v1.15 to v2.2.x you will need to first upgrade to v2.0.5 as pre v1.16 indexes can't be rebuilt with versions greater than v2.0.5.

so the process goes:

1. Upgrade to 2.0.5
2. Rebuild Indexes
3. Upgrade to 2.2.1 (or latest version)
4. Rebuild Indexes

Note: When indexes are rebuilt, they are done in memory, so if you have large tables, or lots of indexes, make sure you have enough memory or do them one at a time.